# Why i'm getting a infinite loop inside this function?

Tags: javascript

```
function renderCarousel(value) {
    let carouselSize = [];
    let tempImg = [];
    for(let i = 0; i<value; i++){   

        tempImg[i] = new Image();
        tempImg[i].onload = function(){
            saveImages();
        }
        function tryLoadImage(){  
            return (tempImg[i].src = 'images/' + i + '.jpg');
        }
        function saveImages(){
            console.log(tryLoadImage(i) + i)
            return(carouselSize[i]=tryLoadImage());
        }
        console.log(tryLoadImage(i) + '2');

}
}
  
renderCarousel(10);
```

Why i'm getting infinite loop inside saveImages funtion? I'm developing a image carousel so i'm creating x amount of image objects, but something goes wrong.

Comment: What is the purpose of `carouselSize`? Its name suggests it will collect sizes, but you assign image URLs to its array.

Comment: Probably because the `onload` function calls `saveImages()`, which in turn calls `tryLoadImage()` which sets the `src` on the image, therefor triggering another `onload`.

Comment: Well what is the value that is being passed into the function?

Comment: The amount of objects that has to be created.

Answer (score 0):

It's not technically an infinite loop, but it's going to trigger your `onload` eventually each time you assign a string to the `src` property, regardless of whether it's already been set before.

Change `tryLoadImage(i)` to `tempImg[i].src` inside the definition of `saveImages()` to avoid infinitely refetching.